# Building custom Quill Editor theme

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, quill

I am trying to put together a custom [Quill](http://quilljs.com/) theme for my application that's based on the [default Snow theme](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/themes/snow.js).

My project is built in ES6, and so I have had to adapt the Snow theme accordingly (mostly replacing instances of `this` with a variable name (`let tooltip = this`).

The area I'm having trouble in is displaying the link tooltip. I am super close in getting it to work (I can add links) but I am now stuck in displaying the preview for a link when the user puts the cursor on a hyperlink.

I have managed to narrow it down to the following line:

```
let [link, offset] = tooltip.quill.scroll.descendant(LinkBlot, range.index);
```

`Range.index` is the correct index of the user's cursor. But `link` is always `null` and offset is always `-1`, no matter if the user's cursor position is on or off a hyperlink.

Why won't the `scroll.descendant` function correctly retrieve the link that the user is on?

Complete theme code:

```
import extend from 'extend';
import Emitter from 'quill/core/emitter';
import BaseTheme, { BaseTooltip } from 'quill/themes/base';
import LinkBlot from 'quill/formats/link';
import { Range } from 'quill/core/selection';


const TOOLBAR_CONFIG = [
    [{ header: ['1', '2', '3', false] }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'link'],
    [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
    ['clean']
];

class ZSSnowTooltip extends BaseTooltip {
    constructor(quill, bounds) {
        super(quill, bounds);
        this.preview = this.root.querySelector('a.ql-preview');
    }

    listen() {
        super.listen();

        let tooltip = this;

        // on action add
        tooltip.root.querySelector('a.ql-action').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (tooltip.root.classList.contains('ql-editing')) {
                tooltip.save();
            } else {
                tooltip.edit('link', tooltip.preview.textContent);
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        // on action remove
        tooltip.root.querySelector('a.ql-remove').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (tooltip.linkRange !== null) {
                tooltip.restoreFocus();
                tooltip.quill.formatText(tooltip.linkRange, 'link', false, Emitter.sources.USER);
                delete tooltip.linkRange;
            }
            event.preventDefault();
            tooltip.hide();
        });

        // on selection change
        tooltip.quill.on(Emitter.events.SELECTION_CHANGE, function(range) {

            // if no range is selected
            if (range === null) {
                return;
            }

            // if range length is 0, try to get a link, if there is a link, show preview box
            if (range.length === 0) {

                let [link, offset] = tooltip.quill.scroll.descendant(LinkBlot, range.index); // link IS ALWAYS NULL

                if (link !== null) {

                    tooltip.linkRange = new Range(range.index - offset, link.length());

                    let preview = LinkBlot.formats(link.domNode);

                    tooltip.preview.textContent = preview;
                    tooltip.preview.setAttribute('href', preview);
                    tooltip.show();
                    tooltip.position(tooltip.quill.getBounds(tooltip.linkRange));

                    return;
                }
            } else {
                delete tooltip.linkRange;
            }
            tooltip.hide();
        });
    }

    show() {
        super.show();
        this.root.removeAttribute('data-mode');
    }
}

class ZSSnowTheme extends BaseTheme {
    constructor(quill, options) {
        if (options.modules.toolbar !== null && options.modules.toolbar.container === null) {
            options.modules.toolbar.container = TOOLBAR_CONFIG;
        }
        super(quill, options);
    }

    extendToolbar(toolbar) {
        this.tooltip = new ZSSnowTooltip(this.quill, this.options.bounds); //eslint-disable-line
        if (toolbar.container.querySelector('.ql-link')) {
            this.quill.keyboard.addBinding({ key: 'K', shortKey: true }, function(range, context) { //eslint-disable-line
                toolbar.handlers['link'].call(toolbar, !context.format.link); //eslint-disable-line
            });
        }
    }
}

ZSSnowTheme.DEFAULTS = extend(true, {}, BaseTheme.DEFAULTS, {
    modules: {
        toolbar: {
            handlers: {
                link: function(value) { // eslint-disable-line

                    if (value) {

                        let range = this.quill.getSelection(),
                            tooltip,
                            preview;

                        if (range === null || range.length === 0) {
                            return;
                        }

                        preview = this.quill.getText(range);

                        if (/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(preview) && preview.indexOf('mailto:') !== 0) {
                            preview = `mailto:${preview}`;
                        }

                        tooltip = this.quill.theme.tooltip;

                        tooltip.edit('link', preview);

                    } else {
                        this.quill.format('link', false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

ZSSnowTooltip.TEMPLATE =
`<span class="title">
  Bezoek link
</span>
<a class="ql-preview" target="_blank" href="about:blank"></a>
<input type="text" />
<span>&nbsp;&#45;&nbsp;</span>
<a class="ql-action">
  <i class="mdi"></i>
  <span class="ql-action-label"></span>
</a>
<a class="ql-remove">
  <i class="mdi mdi-delete"></i>
  Verwijder
</a>`;

export default ZSSnowTheme;
```

Comment: It may be a build issue where the `import LinkBlot from 'quill/formats/link';` LinkBlot may be different than the one Quill registered with Quill so the descendant check will fail. One way to find out is to instead do `Quill.import('formats/link');` to see if that works?

Comment: Ok, I've removed `import LinkBlot from 'quill/formats/link';` from the theme file, and then added 
```let zsLinkBlot = Quill.import('formats/link');
Quill.register({
    'formats/zsLinkBlot': zsLinkBlot
});``` in the file where I instantiate the editor. But I'm unclear as to how I now access the registered zsLinkBlot in the theme definition?

Comment: If I log the output of LinkBlot to the console I'm seeing ```function Link() {
     _classCallCheck(this, Link);

     return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Link.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Link)).apply(this, arguments));
    }```. That's correct right?

Comment: Copying and pasting the contents of `quill/formats/link.js` at the top of the theme file to make sure it can be read from the theme file, doesn't make a difference. Also, when I place console.logs in the linkBlot code, I notice it is never called.

Comment: My suggestion was to replace `import LinkBlot from 'quill/formats/link';` with `let LinkBlot = Quill.import('formats/link');`. All these other steps are just adding noise.

Comment: Could you please tell me how do you import your custom theme (ZSSnowTooltip) in Quill Editor ?